# sorting mails by subject content

Tags: linux, email, procmail

I'm receiving several mails per day from different senders with different subjects. Usually, there is some identifier (integer) that is within the `Subject:`, and I'd like to sort mails according to that identifier. The parsing of the identifier shouldn't be a problem. However, there is no pre-define range of integers that are valid. 
What I'd like to have is mail with same identifier somehow bundeled together, be it that these mails are stored in a separate folder per identifier, or listed within a conversation such that mail programs display them as connected.

What I'm running right now is a `getmail/procmail` combination to fetch those mails. 
What I need is some idea how that could the problem could be solved. If somebody has a hint how to find a solution, preferrably with `procmail`, let me know. Thanks!

Example:

mail1: `From: User1          Subject: message for ID 1234`

mail2: `From: User2          Subject: message for ID 4567`

mail3: `From: User3          Subject: ID 1234 finished`

mail4: `From: User1          Subject: starting ID 9999`

mail5: `From: User2          Subject: finished ID 9999`

What I'd like to have is all messages with identical ID in the `Subject:` bundled, for the example above that would be 3 'buckets': `1234`, `4567`, `9999`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Could you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first integer from the Subject: header and use that as the name of the folder to save to,

```
:0
* ^Subject:[^0-9]*\/[0-9]+
$MATCH
```

If you would like for the folder to be a Maildir folder instead of a flat Berkeley mbox file, use `$MATCH/.` instead.

The special token `\/` causes Procmail to store the input string which matches the regex after this token in the variable `MATCH`.